# Retrieve the table data with xpath and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have HTML with looks basically like the following

```
....
<div id="a">
<table class="a1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="a11.html>a11</a>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="a12.html>a12</a>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
</div>
...
```

The following coding in C# I used, however, I cannot retrieve the URL in this stage

```
IWebElement baseTable =  driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(TableID));
// gets all table rows
ICollection<IWebElement> rows = baseTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
// for every row
IWebElement matchedRow = null;
foreach(var row in rows)
{
Console.Write (row.FindElements(By.XPath("td/a")));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you gave us invalid markup. Right one:

```html
<div id="a">
    <table class="a1">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="a11.html">a11</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="a12.html">a12</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you have only one anchor in table row, you should use this code to retrieve url:

```
IWebElement baseTable = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(TableID));
// gets all table rows
ICollection<IWebElement> rows = baseTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
// for every row
IWebElement matchedRow = null;
foreach (var row in rows)
{    
    Console.WriteLine(row.FindElement(By.XPath("td/a")).GetAttribute("href"));    
}
```

You need to get `href` attribute of found element. Otherwise, `row.FindElement(By.XPath("td/a")` will print type name of the `IWebElement` inherited class, because it is an some type object, not string.

Comment: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"/td/a/"}

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a valid xpath to me

```
Console.Write (row.FindElements(By.XPath("td/a")));
```

try

```
Console.Write (row.FindElements(By.XPath("/td/a")));
```